# Change background color of QMenu item

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Looked everywhere, and could not find a solution I could apply.

Simple case scenario. I have a submenu with 2 entries.

```
menu = QMenu("MainMenu",  self )
submenu = QMenu("Submenu",  menu )
menu.addMenu( submenu )

submenu.addAction(  QIcon(""), "entry 1", myFuncs.func1 )
submenu.addAction(  QIcon(""), "entry 2", myFuncs.func2 )
```

For the time being, I just added a line which at least changes all the items' background colors:

```
submenu.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" % col_brightGray.name())
```

But. 
I would like to change the background color for each of the entries to different shades.
Im sure there is a way, but after trying quite a few, I couldnt nail it.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

QAction not supporting setStylesheet because its not QWidget, Check this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenu

Comment: Indeed. Thank you.
Just wondering of alternatives. I am not looking at setting a color on the action. But on the menu entry. 
I read through that document a few times. And while the answer may be in using QMenu::item unfortunately I do not know how translate that into the code above.. or python, having tried a few times.

Comment: `self.mainMenu.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item {background-color: lightblue; }")` should do that for item right ? but anyway it will apply same as like to all items from the menu.

Comment: Thanks for that. It gave me a chance to try a few more things. It is clear, Im missing the point somewhere. 
Nonetheless, for the sake of it, I tried this: 
`submenu.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item[text ='entry 1'] {background-color: blue; }")` 
and this: 
`actionEntry1 = submenu.addAction( QIcon(""), "entry 1", myFuncs.func1 ) 
submenu.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item#actionEntry1 {background-color: blue; }")`
No errors. But no colors either